# How to get selected option using Selenium WebDriver with Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, junit4

I want to **get the selected label** or value of a **drop down** using Selenium WebDriver and then **print** it on the **console**.

I am able to select any value from the drop down, but I am not able to retrieve the selected value and print it:

```
Select select = new 
Select(driver.findElement(By.id("MyDropDown"))).selectByVisibleText(data[11].substring(1 , data[11].length()-1));
WebElement option = select.getFirstSelectedOption();
```

But all my efforts were in vain. How do I get the selected option?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You should be able to get the text using `getText()` (for the option element you got using `getFirstSelectedOption()`):

```
Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select")));
WebElement option = select.getFirstSelectedOption();
String defaultItem = option.getText();
System.out.println(defaultItem );
```

Comment: I would add for future readers that we need to import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select to work on Select elements.

Comment: getFirstSelectedOption throws a  org.openqa.selenium.NotFoundException when no option is selected.  I would recommend catching that exception as a defensive measure.

Answer (score 20):

Completing the answer:

```
String selectedOption = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("Type the xpath of the drop-down element"))).getFirstSelectedOption().getText();

Assert.assertEquals("Please select any option...", selectedOption);
```

Answer (score 7):

In Selenium Python it is:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

def get_selected_value_from_drop_down(self):
    try:
        select = Select(WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'data_configuration_edit_data_object_tab_details_lb_use_for_match'))))
        return select.first_selected_option.get_attribute("value")
    except NoSuchElementException, e:
        print "Element not found "
        print e
```

Answer (score 3):

On the following option:

```
WebElement option = select.getFirstSelectedOption();
option.getText();
```

If from the method `getText()` you get a blank, you can get the string from the value of the option using the method `getAttribute`:

```
WebElement option = select.getFirstSelectedOption();
option.getAttribute("value");
```

Answer (score 0):

short answer

```
Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select")));
System.out.println("selected items from the dropdown"+ select.getFirstSelectedOption().getText());
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var option = driver.FindElement(By.Id("employmentType"));
        var selectElement = new SelectElement(option);
        Task.Delay(3000).Wait();
        selectElement.SelectByIndex(2);
        Console.Read();
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.