# ddl index to Console.Writeline C# Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, dropdown

I am trying to print out the value I am selecting from a dropdown list.

```
SelectElement selector = new SelectElement(ddlRegisters);
selector.SelectByIndex(1);
String regSelect = selector.Options[1].Text.ToString();
Console.WriteLine("The User Selected  "+regSelect+".");
```

But this isn't working can anyone provide clarification?

Comment: What exactly is "isn't working"?

Comment: @Guy I am successfully able to get the index from the ddl but I am running a Console.WriteLine statement after to capture the value of what drop down text I selected. If i comment out the bottom two lines my code works as intended so I simply want to report on what I am finding.

Comment: Its still not clear. You get exception? nothing is printed? something else? post **all** relevant data, including stack trace if you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use code like below

```
 SelectElement selector = new SelectElement(ddlRegisters);
 selector.SelectByIndex(1);
WebElement option = select.GetFirstSelectedOption();
 String regSelect   option .Text
Console.WriteLine("The User Selected  "+regSelect+".");
```

More details go link:
[How to get selected option using Selenium WebDriver with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11934966/how-to-get-selected-option-using-selenium-webdriver-with-java)

Answer (score 0):

This is no longer an issue, came back this morning to re run the code and it works. Not exactly sure what I missed yesterday but used this code:

```
        ddlRegisters.Click();
        SelectElement selector = new SelectElement(ddlRegisters);
        selector.SelectByIndex(1);
         String regSelect =   selector.Options[1].Text.ToString();
         Console.WriteLine("The User Selected  "+regSelect+".");
```