# Read option text from drop down values in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
List<WebElement> statusvalues = driver.findElements(By.id("ddlStatus"));
for (WebElement option : statusvalues)
{
  System.out.println(option.getText());         
}
```

This is the script I have used to write.

System not providing the error but I didn't get the result. There are five drop down values I need to write in the output. The `HTML` code is given below.

```
<select id="ddlStatus" name="Status" class="full-width" data-role="dropdownlist" style="display: none;">
    <option value="" selected="selected"> -- Select -- </option>
    <option value="11">Arts</option>
    <option value="13">Science</option>
    <option value="14">Engineering</option>
    <option value="64">Law</option>
    <option value="85">Teaching</option>
    <option value="87">Journalist</option>
</select>
```

Just exploring the selenium webdriver and how to write the drop down values in the output.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get selected option using Selenium WebDriver with Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11934966/how-to-get-selected-option-using-selenium-webdriver-with-java)

Answer (score 1):

`List<WebElement> statusvalues = driver.findElements(By.id("ddlStatus"));`

> it's an element and not collection of elements so you need to do:

```
WebElement selectElement = driver.findElement(By.id("ddlStatus"));
```

In that element you have options so you can make collection:

```
List<WebElement> options = selectElement.findElements(By.tagName("option"));
```

> and now you can loop...

Try:

```
List<WebElement> statusvalues = driver.findElement(By.id("ddlStatus")).findElements(By.tagName("option"));
for (WebElement option : statusvalues)
{
   System.out.println(option.getText());         
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the best way you should try using [`Select`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/Select.html) for drop down as below :-

```
Select sel = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("ddlStatus")));
List<WebElement> options = sel.getOptions();
for (WebElement option : options)
{
  System.out.println(option.getText());         
}
```

**Note**:- `driver.findElements(By.id("ddlStatus"));` only provides you the list of all `Elements` which has id `ddlStatus` so in this case **you could get only the drop down element here not it's option**.

Hope it will help you..:)

Answer (score 0):

Also you can try this

```
   List <WebElement> options = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='ddlStatus']/option"));
   for(WebElement option : options)
   {
       System.out.println(option.getText());         
    }
```

You can also handle the dropdowns in 3 other ways as follows,

new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("ddlStatus"))).selectByVisibleText("Particular Text");

new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("ddlStatus"))).selectByIndex(Particular index);

new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("ddlStatus"))).selectByValue("Particular value");