# Return all Select web elements as List in Selenium

Tags: java, angularjs, selenium

**Not a duplicate:** I am not asking for the `<option>` within a `<select>`. I would like to return the `<select>` web elements themselves as a List. When achieved, the list should have a size of 2.

---

I have only found `driver.findElements()` that returns a `List<WebElement>`.

How do I return a `List<Select>` by `ng-model="income.frequency"`?

(Note: I have [ngWebDriver](https://github.com/paul-hammant/ngWebDriver) so I can use `ByAngular.model("income.frequency")` as locator.)

**HTML:**
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read option text from drop down values in selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38304586/read-option-text-from-drop-down-values-in-selenium)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to match elements by their attribute, you can use the CSS selector:

```
By.cssSelector("<tag>[<attribute>='<value>']")
```

And in context:

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("select[ng-model='income.frequency']"));
```

**Edit**: According to [Selenium documentation](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/Select.html), you can create a `Select` with a very straight-forward constructor. Hence, if you want a list of `Select` objects, just construct a new list:

```
List<Select> selectList = new ArrayList<>();
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("select[ng-model='income.frequency']")); 
for(WebElement element : elements) {
    selectList.add(new Select(element);
}
```

Comment: If you'd like a list of `Select`s, you can use its constructor with each WebElement: `new Selector(WebElement element)`

Comment: @silver Hi! I've edited my answer. Let me know if it works for you

Comment: Thank you! Selenium doesn't seem to have this by default yet but your solution is elegant. Upvoted and accepted.