# How to get the value attribute of the selected option in a dropdown using selenium with python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, drop-down-menu, automated-tests, html-select

I have a selenium code (using python) that select a value in a dropdown using the select_by_value method of the 'Select' package in selenium.

[image: Picture of html code]

As you can see in the picture, I input the value `1` in the code and it selects "Poste" which is the text associated with the value `1`.

My question is if there is a way to get the value that was selected after the select process.

I know that with the first_selected_option method I can go get the text of the option selected with :

```
selected_value = options_com.first_selected_option
sv = selected_value.text
print(sv)
```

So is there a way to return the value selected, in this exemple the `value = "1"`, instead of the text.

Comment: You can find the working solution here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11934966/how-to-get-selected-option-using-selenium-webdriver-with-java . Refer to the Python solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get selected option using Selenium WebDriver with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11934966/how-to-get-selected-option-using-selenium-webdriver-with-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`first_selected_option`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.select.html#selenium.webdriver.support.select.Select.first_selected_option) attribute returns the first selected option in this select tag (or the currently selected option in a normal select).

---

### Solution

To print the value of the *value* attribute of the selected option you can use the *`get_attribute()`* method as follows:

```
select = Select(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//select[@id='client.select.communication']))
select.select_by_value("1")
print(select.first_selected_option.get_attribute("value")) # prints -> 1
```

**Note** : You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use regular `get_attribute()` function

```
select = Select(driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "yout_selector"))
select.select_by_visible_text("visible_text")
selected_option = select.first_selected_option
option_value = selected_option.get_attribute("value")
print("Value of selected option is:" + option_value )
```

`first_selected_option` propert convert item into Webelement. so, you can use regular Webelement functions to do any operation you want.